# Parsing image link from media:thumbnail tag of RSS feed android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rss

I'm trying to parse data from this RSS feed

http://www.thedailystar.net/frontpage/rss.xml

I'm using AsyncTask and I can parse all other tags except "media:thumbnail" 
Here's the code

`for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Node currentchild = items.item(i);
                if (currentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    NewsItems item=new NewsItems();
                    NodeList itemchilds = currentchild.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node current = itemchilds.item(j);
                        if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                            item.setTitle(current.getTextContent());
                        }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                            item.setDescription(current.getTextContent());
                        }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")){
                            item.setMedia(current.getTextContent());//This is not working
                        }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                            item.setUrl(current.getTextContent());
                        }
                    }`

I've checked the previous answers regarding this problem, but none of them are working for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getTextContent()` isn't working because that node doesn't have any text content.

You have to access the "url" attribute of the node.

`getAttributes().getNamedItem("url").getTextContent()`

Comment: Thanks! 
I had to change it to 


current.getAttributes().getNamedItem("url").getTextContent()